# Drag and drop in multiple browser windows / tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

Wrote some code to drag and drop elements to other elements. This works fine.

```js
var currentDragElement = null;
var draggableElements = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable="true"]');


[].forEach.call(draggableElements, function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
    element.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    element.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    element.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    element.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
    element.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
});

function handleDragStart(event) {
    currentDragElement = event.target;
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.dataset.uuid);
}


function handleDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    return false;
}

function handleDragEnter(event) {
    this.classList.add('over');
}

function handleDragLeave(event) {
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

function handleDrop(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    if(currentDragElement == event.target) {
        return;
    }

    console.log('dragged element ', currentDragElement.dataset.uuid , ' on element ', event.target.dataset.uuid)

    return false;
}

function handleDragEnd(event) {
    [].forEach.call(draggableElements, function (element) {
        element.classList.remove('over');
    });
}
```

```css
section {
    border: solid 5px green;
    margin: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}

[draggable="true"]:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
}

[draggable="true"] {
    cursor: move;
    background-color: #acacac;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.over[draggable="true"] {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="1.1">draggable 1.1</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="1.2">draggable 1.2</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="1.3">draggable 1.3</div>
</section>

<section>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="2.1">draggable 2.1</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="2.2">draggable 2.2</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="2.3">draggable 2.3</div>
</section>
```

But what I want is the ability to have two open windows from the same browser and then drag and drop the `draggable="true"` elements from one window into the other.

As my code is now that does not work because

```
var currentDragElement = null;
```

remains `null` if draging from other window/tab. The question is how can I get the drag start element if started in other window or tab of same browser? So I want the console to state the same if dragging from different windows as it does now if drag and drop in same window.

Please NO jQuery answers, thanks for helping!

Comment: "The question is how can I get the drag start element if started in other window or tab of same browser? So I want the console to state the same if dragging from different windows as it does now if drag and drop in same window." you can't javascript is executed separated per tab

Comment: Well if draggable between windows/tabs is not possible, you could make a pastebin using localstorage perhaps?

Comment: Dragging between windows seems to work in IE Edge.

Comment: @RaymondNijland correct, the questions remains though. I strongly believe there must be a way.

Comment: @Mouser from what I know I will have the exact same problem also with localstorage.

Comment: @RaymondNijland it's working have a look at the answer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [@Mouser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4364303/mouser) pointed out localstorage does the trick even without any ajax request or the like..

Tested in Google Chrome only

The use of localstorage is not permitted in SO fiddles so if anyone wants to try this out copy the following file save it, open it in two browser windows and have fun with drag and drop

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>drag - drop - demo</title>
    <style>

        section {
            border: solid 5px green;
            margin: 20px;
            float: left;
            width: 40%;
        }

        [draggable="true"]:hover {
            opacity: 0.6;
        }

        [draggable="true"] {
            cursor: move;
            background-color: #acacac;
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 10px;
        }

        .over[draggable="true"] {
            background-color: orange;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="1.1">draggable 1.1</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="1.2">draggable 1.2</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="1.3">draggable 1.3</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="1.4">draggable 1.4</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="1.5">draggable 1.5</div>
</section>

<section>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="2.1">draggable 2.1</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="2.2">draggable 2.2</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="2.3">draggable 2.3</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="2.4">draggable 2.4</div>
    <div draggable="true" data-uuid="2.5">draggable 2.5</div>
</section>

<script>

    var draggableElements = document.querySelectorAll('[draggable="true"]');

    [].forEach.call(draggableElements, function(element) {
        element.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart, false);
        element.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
        element.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
        element.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
        element.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
        element.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd, false);
    });

    function handleDragStart(event) {
        localStorage.setItem('currentDragElement', event.target.dataset.uuid);
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.dataset.uuid);
    }


    function handleDragOver(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
        return false;
    }

    function handleDragEnter(event) {
        this.classList.add('over');
    }

    function handleDragLeave(event) {
        this.classList.remove('over');
    }

    function handleDrop(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        if(localStorage.getItem('currentDragElement') == event.target.dataset.uuid) {
            return;
        }

        currentDragElement = document.querySelector('[data-uuid="'+localStorage.getItem('currentDragElement')+'"]');

        console.log('dragged element ', currentDragElement , ' on element ', event.target)

        localStorage.setItem('currentDragElement', null);

        return false;
    }

    function handleDragEnd(event) {
        [].forEach.call(draggableElements, function (element) {
            element.classList.remove('over');
        });
    }


</script>

</body>
</html>
```